# Create new table for every Content $type in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, database-design, content-management-system, cakephp-2.2

**Description of Goal**

Trying to make a CMS (for internal use, but on many sites) with CakePHP.

I'd like to be able to have a generic `Content` model, then have many different user-generated  content `types`.

This would be simple to do, but my single `contents` table would eventually become massive if every piece of content on the site was in it.  I'd like to split it into tables to help query times/site speed...etc.

My thought (not sure if possible) would be to somehow tell CakePHP that if the `type` field of  the Content is "article", that it should use the `content_articles` table...etc  These tables would be generated `afterSave` (I suppose) when creating a new `content_type`.

Would be nice to give them options of which fields the specific content-type would use - even manage this by adding/removing fields...etc, then only generate those fields in the table, and somehow do validation on them based on the `content_fields` table data.

```
//my thoughts on tables:    
content_types //id, name, description, use_table
content_fields //id, name, content_type_id, required, field_type, max_chars
content_articles //generated by code
content_people //generated by code
```

**Questions:**

Is it even possible?  Are there better ways to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhapse use a key value table for content rather than a standard table?  The utils plugin from CakeDC can do just that with a supported RDBMS.

Or, you could set this model to use a key value data source like MongoDB, which is a great use case for using NoSQL.  I'd probably take that approach if you are talking about massive key value stores and a changing schema.  There's a plugin for MongoDb on github.